# How to Choose a Projected Coordinate System for Nepal?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, nepal

I am working on a project mapping the tiger habitats in Nepal (predominantly along the southern border of the country) and I am not sure which coordinate system / projection I should be working in.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

There are likely several coordinate systems that can be used for Nepal.  However, this one is probably a good start.

[WGS84 / UTM Zone 45N](http://georepository.com/crs_32645/WGS-84-UTM-zone-45N.html)

It looks like there is a Datum for Nepal also.  [Nepal 1981](http://georepository.com/datum_1111/Nepal-1981.html).

Comment: Choosing a projection will depend of the objective/purpose of the map. What do you want to preserve, the shape, area, scale, or direction? It would be useful if you can add more information about the project you are working on.